# AntiForgery Token in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, csrf, razor-pages, antiforgerytoken

I am working in a Razor pages project. In ASP.NET Core, `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is applied for preventing cross-site request forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks.

And I read an article about it:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/anti-forgery-validation-asp-net-core/

*This defense strategy works just as long as the controller’s code that handles the POST double-checks that it is receiving a hidden field named __RequestVerificationToken and a cookie with the same name.*

By using postman, I can just simply copy the cookies value and the antiforgery token, and append it with the request so that I can post without visiting the page. And the cookies and token can be used repeatedly.

My question is, how can I do to prevent users/hackers calling the handlers/controllers without visiting the page and ensure that the token only can be used one time?

Do I have to write my own solutions for this? Or Microsoft already provided a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The antiforgery token prevents csrf attacks. It does this by denying post requests that only contain the cookie. If the attacker has access to the antiforgery token then it is over. This is why the token must change when you log in. And it must be invalidated when you log out. It doesn’t necessarily need to change for each request.

https://owasp.org/www-community/Anti_CRSF_Tokens_ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

There are many strategies.  Microsoft does not recommend you add the token to your cookies collection, but if you do, you must use HTTPS.  As you know, cookies are exposed in each request.  You can strengthen them with HttpOnly and Secure.  But if you add HttpOnly, you can't read it yourself.

A better approach is to use headers because your header won't persist after the request is over.

As for Microsoft, here's a good resource: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0)